# How do you Implement an interface in F#

Tags: f#

I have an interface in C# like this:

```
public interface IMessageOptions
{
    int ReceiveTimeout { get; set; }
    int PeekTimeout { get; set; }
    bool Transactional { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to implement it in F# like this:

```
type Settings() =
    interface IMessageOptions with
        member this.PeekTimeout: int with get, set
        member this.ReceiveTimeout: int with get, set // error at start of this line
        member this.Transactional: bool with get, set
```

But I get an error after the first property saying:

> "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in pattern"

How should this be written?

Are auto properties not allowed in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want automatically implemented properties, then [this is the syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx):

```
type Settings() =
    interface IMessageOptions with
        member val PeekTimeout : int = 0 with get, set
        member val ReceiveTimeout : int = 0 with get, set
        member val Transactional : bool = false with get, set
```

Notice that you explicitly have to define the default value.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the syntax for that:

```
type Settings() =
   interface IMessageOptions with
      member val PeekTimeout = 0 with get, set
      member val ReceiveTimeout = 0 with get, set
      member val Transactional = false with get, set
```

The differences are:

- Use `val` instead of `this.`
- Define the default values explicitly
- You don't have to specify the types (although you can)

For the reference, here is how you would define the interface itself in F#:

```
type IMessageOptions =
  abstract member PeekTimeout : int with get, set
  abstract member ReceiveTimeout : int with get, set
  abstract member Transactional : bool with get, set
```